# Labeling stacked histogram bins with frequency of only one of the stacks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've made a histogram of some data. It represents a bunch of stars, some of which have been observed, others of which have not. The white space represents the ones not observed. I would like to make it so that above the bins where there is white space, it would label the amount of white counts in those bins, but ignore the green and orange. If above the bins is complex, then below them is fine as well. Wherever is simplest. Here's the plot and the code:

[image: Plot]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib import font_manager

# hfont = {'fontname':'Computer Modern'}

filename = ("master.kkids.obslist")

datadata = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=14,dtype=str)

x = datadata[:,7]
y = datadata[:,8]
u = datadata[:,18]
v = datadata[:,19]
z = datadata[:,20]

yesGEM = (v == "Y") & (u == "GemN")
yesDCT = (v == "Y") & (u == "DCT")
no = (v == "N")

x1 = x.astype(float)
y1 = y.astype(float)
x2 = x1*24/360

colors = ['green', 'orange', 'white']
labels = ['GemN','DCT','Not Observed']

plt.xlim(0,24)

plt.hist((x2[yesGEM],x2[yesDCT],x2[no]), 24, label=labels, color=colors, histtype='bar', stacked=True)

plt.legend(fancybox=True,shadow=True)

plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Right Ascension (h)')

plt.savefig('kkids.hist.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern can be to loop on your `x` axis, for each stack check if there is a 'Not Observed', if so, fetch the values of `GemN` + `DCT` + (`Not Observed` / 2) for this observation, then use these two values as x and y to plot the desired text (i.e the value of *not observed*) using `plt.text(x, y, text)`.

So if y understand correctly your dataset, i guess something like this should do the job :

```
# Get the returned arrays from plt.hist, they contain stacked frequencies
phist = plt.hist((x2[yesGEM],x2[yesDCT],x2[no]), 24, label=labels,
                 color=colors, histtype='bar', stacked=True)
plt.legend(fancybox=True,shadow=True)
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Right Ascension (h)')
# Reshape the frequencies values :
stack_plots = \
    np.concatenate(phist[0]).reshape(len(labels), len(phist[0][0])).T

for nb_x, stack in enumerate(stack_plots):
    # 'stack' is an array with the frequency of [GEM, DCT + GEM, CDT + GEM + NO]
    if stack[2] - stack[1] != 0: # If there is Not Observed..
        # Compute the coords for the text :
        x_text = nb_x
        y_text = stack[1] + (stack[2] - stack[1]) / 2
        # And plot it:
        plt.text(x_text, y_text, round(stack[2] - stack[1]), verticalalignment='center')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The value in the data file is basically a column that says "observed" and there will be "Y" or "N." The white space in the histogram represents the amount in that bin that were "N" (there are other criteria that apply only to the "Y" answers). Basically, I just need to label the amount of "Ns" in each bin. All other data can be ignored.

Comment: @uhurulol Youre welcome! I modified my answer, trying to fit your data structure (it's seems to work in my test)

Comment: This works great! Quick question, though---the numbers come out formatted with one decimal place. Do you know how I could get them to be displayed just as integers?

Comment: @uhurulol i guess you can try `plt.text(x_text, y_text, '{:.0f}'.format(round(stack[2] - stack[1])), verticalalignment='center')`